# Django - Inline search for users in admin

Tags: python, django

I need to create an "inline search" in my admin page, and I don't know where to start from.

The idea is replace that "----" for the search bar, or just let to type in the "User: " bar, that doesn't matter. If possible, I wanted to do the same thing in the "Account: " bar.

Note: when you click the bar, it opens a column with data etc.
[Click here to see the printscreen, please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Jno.png)

```
# admin.py

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name' , 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser' )

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreateForm
    prepopulated_fields = {'username': ('first_name' , 'last_name')}
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser' ),
        }),
    )

class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'id', 'document', 'subscriber_code']
    list_filter = ['status']

class UserAccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['account__id', 'account__name', 'user__first_name', 'account__subscriber_code']
    list_filter = ['is_superuser']
```

```
# userAccount.py

from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .account import Account
from .resource import Resource


class UserAccount(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        db_column='uacId',
        primary_key=True
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        db_column='uacUseId',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account,
        db_column='aucAccId',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column='uacCreatedAt',
        default=timezone.now
    )
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(
        db_column='uacIsSuperuser',
        default=False
    )
    disabled_resources = models.ManyToManyField(
        Resource,
        blank=True,
        db_table="UserAccountDisabledResources"
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        db_column='uacStatus',
        max_length=30,
        choices = [(x,x) for x in ['ACTIVE', 'DISABLE']],
        default='ACTIVE'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.account.name, self.user.email)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'UserAccount'
```

Comment: Adding a `search_fields ` in UserAdmin won't solve this problem?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to have this search capability on the admin page that lists all the objects, or the admin page for a single object? (I think AzyCrw4282's suggestion works for the list page, but not the single-object page.)

Comment: yeah, the idea is build it inline, for the specific single object (for example User)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I discovered that django has an build in function for what I was planning to do.
It's the 'autocomplete_fields'.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Thanks everybody that tried to help :)